# How to align <td> in child table/form with parent <td>'s

Tags: css, angular

I have a parent form with a two-column table in it, and within the table is a child form/table, also with two columns. In my child form/table, both columns are getting squeezed to align with the first column of the parent table. How do I make the first child column align with the first parent column, and the second child column align with the second parent column?

I've created special classes and to ensure uniform formatting, made sure to apply the same class to both the parent and child `<table>`, `<th>`, and `<td>` elements.

Parent Template

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%" [formGroup]="form">
  <h3>Form</h3>
  <table class="main-table">
    <tr>
      <th class="category-header; enroll">Category</th>
      <th class="input-header; enroll">Input</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of memberKeys">
      <ng-container *ngIf="topLevel(key); else subTable">
        <td class="enroll">{{key}}:&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="enroll"><input type="text" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" formControlName="{{key}}"/></td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #subTable>
        <app-sub-enroll-form [objEnroll]="member[key]" [formGroup]="form" [form]="form"></app-sub-enroll-form> 
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Child Template (selector: "app-sub-enroll-form")

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <table class="main-table">
    <tr>
        <th class="category-header; enroll">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="input-header; enroll">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let subkey of allKeys">
      <td class="enroll">{{subkey}}:&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="enroll"><input type="text" name="{{subkey}}" placeholder="Enter {{subkey}} Here" formControlName="{{subkey}}"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<form>
```

CSS

```
 table.main-table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30%; 
    border:blue
  }

  td.enroll, th.enroll {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 15%;
  }

  .category-header {
    width: 15%;
  }

  .input-header {
    width: 15%;
  }
```

I want each child column to align with the corresponding parent column, but instead both child columns are squeezed together so that the two child columns combined align with the first parent column. Many thanks in advance if any advice.

Comment: in your code i saw two tables.So do you want to load the table with Catergory and the Input If a  conditon is true and load the other table if the conditon is false.(load the table in child-component)

Comment: No, I load both tables. One is the parent, rendered by the <ng-container> in the parent template, and the other is the child, rendered by the <ng-template> in the parent template (and by the child template). The problem is how to make the columns in the parent and child tables align.

Comment: If you want to do it quickly you can load that child component  in two columns  inside <ng-template #subTable> <td><[cvalue]="1" childComponet></td><td><childComponet [cvalue]="2" ></td> 
       </ng-template> and hide the second column in child table in first column of parent table wise versa. Using *ngIF  considering cvalue binded to   the each component

Comment: That's a brilliant idea, @Thivanka Saranatha, and it works . . . almost. The only problem now is that because there are now two separate child components per table row, the rows in the two child components don't quite align. Almost there!